# Change Default Column Values on multi-choice column

Tags: document-library, multiple-values, default-value

I know can set folder specific Default Values by going to "Change Default Column Values' as [specified here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/automatic-tagging-based-from-a-folder-how-to-get-your-users-to-eat-their-vegetables-without-them-knowing-it.aspx).  I also know that I can specify a default value on a multi-choice column by selecting `Calculated value` on the Default value and specifying the default as so: `=";#Choice1;#Choice2;#"` .  But I cannot seem to figure out how to specify multichoice defaults from the 'Change Default Column Values' page.  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to do this is to use the Calculated column as the column default value and have folder level defaults overwrite that column level default as necessary.  It seems there is not a workaround if you need multiple defaults on a multi-choice column.